# NullInjectorError: No provider for String! in angular 6

Tags: angular, dependency-injection

Parent class

```
import { BadRequestError } from './../common/bad-request-error';
import { NotFoundError } from './../common/not-found-error';
import { AppError } from './../common/app-error';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import { Injectable, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { throwError} from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DataService {
  constructor(private url: string , private http: Http) {
 }

getAll() {
 return this.http.get(this.url).pipe(catchError(this.handleError));
}

delete(id) {
  return this.http.delete(this.url + '/' + id)
   .pipe(
    catchError(this.handleError));
 }

update(resource) {
  return this.http.patch(this.url + '/' + resource.id, 
    JSON.stringify({isRead: true})).pipe(
      catchError(this.handleError));
  }

create(resource) {
 return this.http.post(this.url , JSON.stringify(resource))
   .pipe(
     catchError(this.handleError)
   );

}

 private handleError(err: Response) {
   if (err.status === 404) {
     return throwError(new NotFoundError());
 } if (err.status === 400) {
   return throwError(new BadRequestError(err.json()));
 }
   return throwError(new AppError(err));
 }
}
```

child Class

```
 import { DataService } from './data.service';
 import { Http } from '@angular/http';
 import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
 providedIn: 'root'
})
export class PostService extends DataService {
  constructor(http: Http) {
    super('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts' , http);
 }

}
```

Getting below error while passing string from child class.

> Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[String]:
>   StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[String]: 
>       NullInjectorError: No provider for String!
>       at NullInjector.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.NullInjector.get
>   (core.js:1062)
>       at resolveToken (core.js:1300)
>       at tryResolveToken (core.js:1244)
>       at StaticInjector.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.StaticInjector.get
>   (core.js:1141)
>       at resolveToken (core.js:1300)
>       at tryResolveToken (core.js:1244)
>       at StaticInjector.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.StaticInjector.get
>   (core.js:1141)
>       at resolveNgModuleDep (core.js:8376)
>       at NgModuleRef_.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.NgModuleRef_.get
>   (core.js:9064)
>       at inject (core.js:1403)

please suggest how to resolve above error.

Comment: You should declare this string outside of the constructor. [Ref below link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47940179/7267442)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any parameter added to service angular will try to inject this by DI system. `DataService` considers the base class for api service in this case and we don't need to make it `injectable`. So just remove the injectable decorator

*DataService*

```
export class DataService {

  constructor(private url: string , private http: Http) {
 }
 ...    

}
```